# Why are my css3 animations so buggy in chrome and edge?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been working on a website, and it's my first attempt at web development. Now since I generally use Firefox, I started by drafting my website out on Firefox. Now I understand the Firefox is Gecko and Chrome and Edge are Webkit, hence there is likely to be some differences between them. All the animations and everything perform really well on Firefox- the custom cursor, the CSS marquee, virtually everything. Is my code just that badly written, or am I doing something wrong?

```js
/*kinda laggy cursor control js */
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: " + e.pageY + "px; left: " + e.pageX + "px;")
})

const cursor2 = document.querySelector('.cursor2');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  cursor2.setAttribute("style", "top: " + e.pageY + "px; left: " + e.pageX + "px;")
})

const links = document.querySelectorAll('a')

links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
    cursor.classList.add('enlarged')
  })
  link.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
    cursor.classList.remove('enlarged')
  })
})
const labels = document.querySelectorAll('label')
labels.forEach(label => {
  label.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
    cursor.classList.add('enlarged')
  })
  label.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
    cursor.classList.remove('enlarged')
  })
})
```

```css
.cursor {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid rgb(83, 83, 83);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: 50ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
  z-index: 800;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: color 100ms ease, top 50ms linear, left 50ms linear, width 500ms ease, height 500ms ease;
}

.cursor2 {
  z-index: 800;
  transition: 10ms;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(83, 83, 83);
  pointer-events: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: absolute;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- outer cursor div-->
<div class="cursor">
</div>
<!-- inner cursor div-->
<div class="cursor2">
</div>
```

The above snippet was for a custom cursor, for which I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfpRZ2t_BrQ) random Youtube tutorial. The guy in the tutorial gets a perfectly decent cursor, and he seems to even be using chrome, where the cursor works perfectly. However when I run my code in chrome, I get an insane degree of lag, with the cursor just teleporting all over the place. Any and all :hover transitions are incredibly abrupt, whereas in Firefox it seems to work perfectly alright.

Comment: Why toggle classes on mouseenter/mouseleave instead of using `:hover`?

Comment: @Ry-♦ I had a bunch of links buried inside a few divs, and I couldn't seem to get it to work, and the selectors are only applicable to sibling elements- though I'm not really sure about that.